# Sorting IP address according to the second field in file

Tags: linux, awk, perl, ksh, sort

in my ksh  script I need to add the following task ( OS - linux/solaris )

I have the following file

```
 more test.txt


 /etc/backup/app 172.1.120      172.110.120 
 /etc/backup/app 172.1.120.12   172.110.120.98 
 /etc/backup/app 192.1.120      192.120.120 
 /etc/backup/app 172.1.120.1      172.110.120.7 
 /var/log/df     193.23.2       193.23.2
 /var/log/df     193.23.2.111   193.23.2.159
```

how to locate all  IP's with **4 octets** in the beginning of the file ,  and then the others IP's with **3 octets**

Remark – sort IP's will be according to the second field

Example of requested file ( after sort )

```
    more test.txt

    /etc/backup/app 172.1.120.12   172.110.120.98 
    /etc/backup/app 172.1.120.1    172.110.120.7
    /var/log/df     193.23.2.111   193.23.2.159
    /etc/backup/app 172.1.120      172.110.120 
    /etc/backup/app 192.1.120      192.120.120 
    /var/log/df     193.23.2       193.23.2
```

Solution can be done with sort or ksh/awk/sed/perl one liner ...etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you have `GNU awk` here is the one-liner you need:

```
$ awk '{n=split($2,ip,".");if(n==4)print $0;else a[$2]=$0}END{n=asorti(a,b);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print a[b[i]]}' file
/etc/backup/app 172.1.120.12   172.110.120.98 
/etc/backup/app 172.1.120.1    172.110.120.7 
/var/log/df     193.23.2.111   193.23.2.159
/etc/backup/app 172.1.120      172.110.120 
/etc/backup/app 192.1.120      192.120.120 
/var/log/df     193.23.2       193.23.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf "%s.,%s\n", $2, $0}' | \
sed -E -e 's/^(([0-9]+\.){4}),/0.\1,/' -e 's/^(([0-9]+\.){3}),/1.\1,/' | \
sort -t. -k 1,1 -k 3,3 | \
sed -E -e 's/^[^,]+,//'`
```

The idea is to:

1. Copy relevant field to beginning of each line and add special separator (comma in this case)
2. Use `sed` to prepend some value that depends on number of octets in IP address (I used 0 for 4 octets and 1 for 3 octets)
3. Sort the values on relevant fields
4. Strip out everything we added

Comment: the problem is that sed -E isnt illegal option on Solaris , is it possible to find other flag to support both OS ( Linux and Solaris ) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat <(awk '{if($2~/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/){print $0}}' test.txt | sort -k 2) <(awk '{if($2~/^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*$/){print $0}}' test.txt | sort -k 2)
```

- Match lines where the second field has 4 octets and sort
- Match lines where the second field ends after 3 octets and sort
- Concatenate the two results together